# компиляция c# под линукс

Tags: c#, linux, компиляция

купил хост на линуксе, сделал чтобы через MSBuild компилировать уже готовый проект на visual studio, но wine или mono не запускают этот компилятор... пробовал переустанавливать, другого компилятора кроме этого не знаю. МНЕ от линукса нужна лишь КОМПИЛЯЦИЯ(( помогите пожалуйста, уже два часа без перерыва гуглю..

Comment: Установите .net core/5 и компилируйте сколько захотите

Comment: @SmorcIRL установил, а что дальше..

Comment: Проект на .NET Framework? Есть возможность .NET 5 использовать?

Comment: @Jagailo возможно есть.. я не очень понимаю как компилировать через .net 5

Comment: компилировать нужно в виндовс совместимый исполняемый файл?

Comment: @eri компилировать в экзешник, через линукс

Comment: Если вам нужна лишь компиляция, то какой смысл покупать хост? Вон вам DevOps от Microsoft, настраивайте и компилируйте как надо. Ну а так, как вы пробовали компилировать и зачем вам тут mono и wine? Открываете директорию с проектом и пишете стандартную команду `dotnet build -r rid`, где `rid` - это [идентификатор системы под которую будет собран проект](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog), а еще лучше `dotnet publish`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 
```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.102/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1180,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks 
```
что делать?

Comment: Ну так извините, вам выше сказали что? Используйте .NET Core или .NET 5.

Comment: `Version=v4.7.2 were not found ` переписывать под 5,0)

Comment: экзешник для какой системы?

Comment: @eri для виндовса

Comment: @ChaYKa собирай под виндовсом. Не мучай себя)

Comment: `уже два часа без перерыва гуглю` потому что гуглить надо не **компиляцию**, а **сборку** приложений, или building applications.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а можно вопрос? а что делать если мой проект не подходит для миграции с .net framework на .net core? можно как нибудь с .net framework собрать?

Comment: Ну, такого быть не может, особенно если проект ваш написан на довольно свежем 4.7.2, ибо изменений в коде там почти нету, а библиотеки должны использовать общий стандарт. Так что, я бы вам посоветовал все же разобраться с этим, найти проблему и перенести проект под .net5. Ну а так, можно конечно и фреймворк, только гемороя ооооочень много получите (самый [простой вариант](https://medium.com/@hudsonmendes/build-net-4-5-on-linux-in-5-minutes-and-see-what-it-is-like-848ea45fc667)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ
Errors:

/root/Bot/Telegram/Telegram.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->

        /root/Bot/Telegram/Bot/Bot.csproj: error : /root/Bot/Telegram/Bor/Bo.csproj: Unable to parse condition "Exists($(ProjectWeaverXml))" : Expected a property at position 8 in condition "Exists($(ProjectWeaverXml))". Missing opening parantheses after the '$'.
что делать??

Comment: это при  xbuild Telegram.sln
пакеты все установил.